# how to read excel file using excelJS & multer

Tags: nestjs, multer, exceljs

I'm trying to read a CSV Excel file using **exceljs** and **multer** for the file upload.

```
@Post('excel')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('excel'))
  async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {

    const workBook = new Excel.Workbook();
    await workBook.csv
      .read(createReadStream(file.buffer))
      .catch((err) => console.log('err'));

    const sheet = workBook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
    const cellValue = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).value;

    return cellValue;
  }
```

But I am getting the Error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of read, you have to use load

```
workBook.xlsx.load(file.buffer)
```